# Multiple ReadData in a Menu ComboBox (MySQL/C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I was trying to show the values of my data in my different tables in these combo boxes which I made. I tried making multiple read data but it's impossible without getting an error. Is there other way to show these values in these different combo boxes?

[Menu Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GezXP.png)

```
 private void VoteMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        displayCandidate();
    }

    public void displayCandidate()
    {
            //Connection
            String connection = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=votingdb;";

            //Inserting Data
            String displayPresident = "SELECT * FROM president";
            String displayVicePresident = "SELECT * FROM vicepresident";
            String displaySecretary = "SELECT * FROM secretary";
            String displayTreasurer = "SELECT * FROM treasurer";
            String displayAuditor = "SELECT * FROM auditor";
            String displayPro = "SELECT * FROM pro";
            MySqlDataReader dataReader;

        //Connection and Inserting of Data
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection))
            {
                //Opening of Connection
                con.Open();


                //FOR PRESIDENT
                using (MySqlCommand votePresident = new MySqlCommand(displayPresident, con))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int votePres = 0;
                        votePres = votePresident.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        dataReader = votePresident.ExecuteReader();
                    //Loop to read the Data
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        String rollPresf = dataReader.GetString("firstName");
                        String rollPresl = dataReader.GetString("lastName");
                        presidentbox.Items.Add(rollPresf + " " + rollPresl);
                    }

                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Failed to Vote" + ex);
                    }

                }
                //FOR VICE PRESIDENT
                using (MySqlCommand voteVicePresident = new MySqlCommand(displayVicePresident, con))
                {

                    try
                    {
                        int voteVpres = 0;
                        voteVpres = voteVicePresident.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        dataReader = voteVicePresident.ExecuteReader();
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Failed to Vote" + ex);
                    }

                }
```

There are more position to be filled, and I also tried making every position to show their values inside my database which has different tables like this

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MULlg.png)

Comment: Wouldnt it be *much* simpler if the candidate's office (Pres, VP, Treas etc) was simply a column indicating what they were a candidate for?

Comment: I was planning to make it to a multiple tables that per combobox can make a query/read the values in each of those tables. If it has a simpler method. I would be glad to hear it.